# How can I troubleshoot and resolve the issue of a subscription plan not updating correctly when using Stripe Webhooks in my coding project?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments, tailwind-css, next.js13

I put my payments in test mode and whenever I purchase with stripe everything works and goes through but it returns me to my website without pro version and the user is still on free plan after paying... How to fix this?

This is using stripe webhooks.

This is my pro-modal that stripe uses for the Pro Plan:

```
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import {
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  DialogDescription,
  DialogFooter,
  DialogHeader,
  DialogTitle,
} from "@/components/ui/dialog"
import { useProModal } from "@/hooks/use-pro-modal";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Separator } from "@/components/ui/separator";
import { useToast } from "@/components/ui/use-toast";

export const ProModal = () => {
  const proModal = useProModal();
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const { toast } = useToast();

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsMounted(true);
  }, []);


  const onSubscribe = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await axios.get("/api/stripe");

      window.location.href = response.data.url;
    } catch (error) {
      toast({
        description: "Something went wrong",
        variant: "destructive",
      });
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }

  if (!isMounted) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Dialog open={proModal.isOpen} onOpenChange={proModal.onClose}>
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogHeader className="space-y-4">
          <DialogTitle className="text-center">
            Upgrade to Pro
          </DialogTitle>
          <DialogDescription className="text-center space-y-2">
            Create
            <span className="text-sky-500 mx-1 font-medium">Custom AI</span>
            Companions!
          </DialogDescription>
        </DialogHeader>
        <Separator />
        <div className="flex justify-between">
          <p className="text-2xl font-medium">
            $9<span className="text-sm font-normal">.99 / mo</span>
          </p>
          <Button onClick={onSubscribe} disabled={loading} variant="premium">
            Subscribe
          </Button>
        </div>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```

This is my settings page in the app:

```
import { SubscriptionButton } from "@/components/subscription-button";
import { checkSubscription } from "@/lib/subscription";

const SettingsPage = async () => {
  const isPro = await checkSubscription();

  return ( 
    <div className="h-full p-4 space-y-2">
      <h3 className="text-lg font-medium">Settings</h3>
      <div className="text-muted-foreground text-sm">
        {isPro ? "You are currently on a Pro plan." : "You are currently on a free plan."}
      </div>
      <SubscriptionButton isPro={isPro} />
    </div>
   );
}
 
export default SettingsPage;
```

Comment: Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I don't think we have enough information here. Solely based of this `const response = await axios.get("/api/stripe"); window.location.href = response.data.url;`, I believe you're creating a Checkout Session from the backend, and returning the Session url. But why can't we see this code ? And although you mention webhooks in your title, I don't see code for your webhook handler here, nor do I know what `checkSubscription()` does.

Comment: I got it to work. I had to run a command in stripe CLI. Weird because I did it once and it didn't work and then I tried again and it worked.